# Reinstall Core Magento

Tags: magento2, installation, repair-tool

Hi I have a website which experiences some error at the backend such as
- cannot place an order from backend

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Composer\Installer\InstallerInterface' not found in ..../vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/MetapackageInstaller.php on line 23
```

- need to refresh every page to make them working properly via CRTL+F5

these are few of errors I have got ...

It seems some file at the core may have been corrupt.

I was thinking to reinstall the Magento same version (not upgrading) M2 2.1.2. Is there a safe way to do it? is run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` a good solution or not?

Comment: Welcome to Magento StackExchange. First do `compose update`